# How to join another table which has duplicate value for same id, and keep left table the same row numbers?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables

table1:

```
id gid   cost
1  1000  123 
2  2000  123 
3  1000  111 
4  3000  222
5  1000  333
```

table2:

```
id gid   name 
1  1000  AAA  
2  2000  BBB  
3  3000  CCC
4  4000  DDD
```

I would like to output

```
gid,name,totalCost
```

So:

```
(select gid,sum(cost) from table1 group by gid) a
left join
(select distinct gid,name from table2) b
on a.gid = b.id
```

works.

Recently table2 supports multiple names for one gid like:

```
id gid   name      feature
1  1000  AAA       xxx
2  2000  BBB  
3  3000  CCC
4  4000  DDD
5  2000  NewName.  yyy
```

So above SQL gives:

```
gid. name.   total
1000 AAA.    4444
2000 BBB     333
2000 NewName 333
```

I would like to have unique gid in the output, if there are multiple names in table2, use one name.

```
gid. name.   total
1000 AAA.    4444
2000 BBB     333
3000 CCC.    333
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.gid,
       MAX(b.name) AS name,
       a.totalCost
FROM (SELECT gid, SUM(cost) AS totalCost FROM table1 GROUP BY gid) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT gid, name FROM table2) b
ON a.gid = b.gid
GROUP BY a.gid, a.totalCost;
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.